# Assigning user declared variable inside mysql while loop results in null

Tags: mysql, sql, variables, user-defined-functions, user-defined

I am trying the following mysql function, which includes a while loop.

```
BEGIN
    SET @total := 5000;
    SET @count := 1;
    SET @total := (SELECT price from item_prices WHERE id=SUBSTRING_INDEX(items,";",1));
    INSERT INTO mytest values (SUBSTRING_INDEX(items,";",1), (SELECT price from item_prices WHERE id=SUBSTRING_INDEX(items,";",1)));
    WHILE items != SUBSTRING_INDEX(items,";",@count) DO
    
        SET @count := @count + 1;
        SET @temp := (SELECT price from item_prices WHERE id=SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(items,";",@count),";",-1));
        SET @total := @total + @temp;
        INSERT INTO mytest values (SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(items,";",@count),";",-1),(SELECT price from item_prices WHERE id=SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(items,";",@count),";",-1)));
    END WHILE;
    RETURN @total;
END;
```

I have used the `mytest` table to debug my values. When I debugged, I can see that my `SELECT` query is returning correct values for all cases. But, in some cases my `@total` variable get converts to `NULL`.
Eg: I pass String "1;2;14"

```
@total = 100
@count = 2, @temp = 200, @total = 300
@count = 3, @temp = 50, @total = NULL

Eg2:I pass String "1;14;15"
val1 = 100, @total = NULL
@count = 2, @temp = 50, @total = NULL
@count = 3, @temp = 75, @total = NULL
```

Also, I can see that, `@total` get `NULL` after a certain point and stays `NULL`, even for the later calls to the function. Can someone explain me the theory here? Should I clear the variable at the end of the function?

Update:
My Complete program:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS get_total;
CREATE FUNCTION get_total(items VARCHAR(45)) RETURNS INT DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN

    SET @total := 5000;
    SET @count := 1;
    SET @total := (SELECT price from item_prices WHERE id=SUBSTRING_INDEX(items,";",1));
    #INSERT INTO mytest values (SUBSTRING_INDEX(items,";",1), @total);
    WHILE items != SUBSTRING_INDEX(items,";",@count) DO
    
        SET @count := @count + 1;
        SET @temp := (SELECT price from item_prices WHERE id=SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(items,";",@count),";",-1));
        SET @total := @total + @temp;
        #INSERT INTO mytest values (SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(items,";",@count),";",-1),@total);
    END WHILE;
    RETURN @total;
END;

CREATE PROCEDURE orderPrices()
BEGIN
    SELECT id, buyer, get_total(items) AS total_price
    FROM orders
    ORDER BY id;
END;
```

Sample Input:

```
orders

id  buyer           items
1   Justin Penrose  1
2   Bertha Neiman   1;2;14
3   John Doe        1;14;15

item_prices

id  price
1   100
2   200
3   500
4   250
14  50
15  75
16  100
```

The function receives a `;` separate list of item `id`'s,
What my function attempt to do is get each id separated from ';'s, retrieve the relevant price from the price table and return the total.

Comment: Provide sample online fiddle which reproduces your issue. Explain the logic of your function in details.

Comment: Use `SELECT .. INTO @variable` instead of `SET @variable := (SELECT ..)`. Convert your function to the stored procedure for debugging purposes and check for errors/warning during the code flow.

Comment: assigning the `SELECT` value to `@temp` variable works without any issue, `@total` is the one that is giving me issues, I updated the question with the requested information.

Comment: @Akina : Yes, it worked, thanks, can you tell me the difference?

Comment: Check if the query returns more than one row.

Comment: No, I checked that with my `INSERT` query, it always added one value to the `mytest` table

Comment: A have not told about the amount of rows inserted into debugging table. I have told about the amount of rows returned by the SELECT used for assigning the value to a variable. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=536cc3c6a01068883b7948b8c94c1cd7

Comment: It should return only 1 value, because there is only 1 corresponding result in the price table with the id use the select query. I don't know any other way to verify that other than the INSERT query I have used here.

Comment: If so then again *Provide sample online fiddle which reproduces your issue.*

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know what a sample online fiddler is, my bad, I can't get this to run in a fiddler, I put the code into a gist with all query to run it if that works, https://gist.github.com/cdwijayarathna/9082210b207595b8b4ddc80f041d6678

Comment: Goto https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e95d9afbfe5d509e612bc84d1526abb8 ,  add definitions and sample data, select proper server version, execute, ensure the issue occured, provide the link.

Comment: Thanks, https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2eac3062090d1105140b87e70dfbc546 I tried the exact same code, but it works without any issue, I got the issue in 8.0.22 and tried 8.0 in the fiddler, May my my code had no issue, but issue in the platform I was running?

Answer (score 0):

The task can be solved by one simple query:

```sql
SELECT orders.id, orders.buyer, SUM(item_prices.price) total_price
FROM orders
JOIN item_prices ON FIND_IN_SET(item_prices.id, REPLACE(orders.items, ';', ','))
GROUP BY orders.id, orders.buyer
ORDER BY id
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5166a5d093abd2eb925901311ad2a0ab)